# r arithmetic on separate dataframes with row titles

Tags: r

I imported some census data from 2 different years and did some clean up. Not all of the variables are numeric but I want to do some arithmetic (difference) then save the result into a new dataframe. Here is some sample data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("Brazil", "Columbia", "Hong Kong"), ward_1 = c(35,25,33), ward_2 = c(22,33,44), continent = c("South America", "South America", "Asia"))
df2 <- data.frame(country = c("Brazil", "Hong Kong", "Columbia"), ward_1 = c(45,62,26), ward_2 = c(77,55,67), continent = c("South America", "Asia", "South America"))
```

Is there a function that can match the entries in the first column then do the arithmetic to columns 2 and 3? Or should the first column be sorted alphabetically before doing any arithmetic?

How do you do arithmetic when there are non-numeric variables in the dataframe?

Comment: Perhaps describe what you actually want? What would the output look like if you did the arithmetic on the sample data. If you are trying to merge the tables, then see `base::merge()`, or `data.table::merge()`, or `dplyr::inner_join / dplyr::left_join, etc`

Answer (score 0):

Start by `match`ing the countries on both data.frames and then subtract based on that index.

```r
i <- match(df1$country, df2$country)
df1$ward_1 - df2$ward_1[i]
#> [1] -10  -1 -29
df1$ward_2 - df2$ward_2[i]
#> [1] -55 -34 -11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To automate the differences, `Map` or `mapply` can process several data sets at once.

```r
Map(\(x, y) x - y, df1[2:3], df2[i, 2:3])
#> $ward_1
#> [1] -10  -1 -29
#> 
#> $ward_2
#> [1] -55 -34 -11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And this can be coerced to data.frame.

```r
as.data.frame(Map(\(x, y) x - y, df1[2:3], df2[i, 2:3]))
#>   ward_1 ward_2
#> 1    -10    -55
#> 2     -1    -34
#> 3    -29    -11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>